# Call functions from function inside an object using for-in Loop(object literal)

Tags: javascript

**Javascript**

I've made an object with properties in which made further functions and nested object. Now,the problem is that nested object and the functions, not displaying on the screen while using for-in loop.

```js
var obj = {
    fname: 'abc',
    lname: 'xyz',
    date: 4,
    year: 2022,
    // Nested object with further a property hobbies.
    nestedObj: {
        hobbies: 'nothing'
    },
    // As you can see, these are the two functions that i want to display using for-in loop

    fun: function () {
        return 0;
    },

    fullname: function () {
        return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname;
    }
};

// i think i am missing something for example any-condition, while declaring the for-in loop.
for (var key in obj) {
    // The break tag is used to display all the object properties to the next line to each other
    document.write(obj[key] + '<br>');
}
```

What do you think? Can you do it? any suggestions would be considerable. Consider yourself heartily thanked!!

Comment: Call functions inside an object using for-in Loop(object literal)

Comment: What's the expected output?